# pull the latest image tag from ECR repo using AWS SDK

Tags: java, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-java

Im trying to pull the latest image tag from the AWS ECR repo using AWS SDK

Im trying to write below code from the documentation and the google search

```java
public class AwsECRTest {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ListTagsForResourceRequest request = new ListTagsForResourceRequest();
        request.setResourceArn("arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:45454512:repository/testrty");
                   
        ListTagsForResourceResult r(ListTagsForResourceRequest request);           
                   
        System.out.println(r.getTags());   
    }
}
```

getting below error

```
    Syntax error on token "ListTagsForResourceResult", record expected
```

not sure , how to pass the `request` object to `ListTagsForResourceResult`

please help / suggest

this is the doc link :
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-ecr/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/ecr/AmazonECR.java

Comment: `listTagsForResource` just returns the AWS resource tags for the ECR repository, not the docker image tags for the images stored in the repository. If you look at other AWS services/resources, every one of them have a `listTagsForResource`. You will need to call `listImages` to get the details of the images in the repository, including their tags.

Comment: @MarkB: Thank you very much.  I will have a look 
Is there any way to get the Latest Tag ? I'm interested in getting latest image tag for image in repository

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to create an object `r` of type `ListTagsForResourceResult` and call a method `r()` simultaneously, unfortunately that's not going to work in Java.

The `ListTagsForResourceResult` object should be returned from a method call from an instance of the `AmazonECR` client, so iou'll need to set up an `AmazonECR` to interact with your ECR repository first, and then call the `listTagsForResource()` method on the client with your request as an argument:

```java
public class AwsECRTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        AmazonECR ecr = AmazonECRClientBuilder.defaultClient();
        
        ListTagsForResourceRequest request = new ListTagsForResourceRequest();
        request.setResourceArn("arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:45454512:repository/testrty");
        
        ListTagsForResourceResult result = ecr.listTagsForResource(request);
        
        System.out.println(result.getTags());
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code . however, the list is empty.  result.getTags() is coming as empty 
but I can see the tags on the AWS console